# Nested Scrollview + Recycler View

Tags: android, material-design, nestedscrollview

I have a layout which has a collapsable image view, along with the GridView in the layout, and many more things in the UI . But the screen is scrolling upto the image scroll, that is it scrolls up only till the header image is not visible. After that it neither scrolls.

How can I solve that ?

Here are my layouts:

Parent Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headerImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/gallery_shop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/telephone_call" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_shop_products_category"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Included Layout:

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAboutShop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_gray"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAboutShopDesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_gray"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="Raju Bakery Store is number one store in the market of Gurgaon. We have all variety of Bakery Items in the city. Special arrangements for marriages and parties"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cardlist_item1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_gray"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="List of Products"/>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/productsGridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:verticalSpacing="14dp">

                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cardlist_item2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_gray"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_slate_gray"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="Raju Bakery Store is number one store in the market of Gurgaon. We have all variety of Bakery Items in the city. Special arrangements for marriages and parties"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image: Expanded layout]

[image: Collapsed Layout]

Answer (score 1):

for doing that remove the line  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from everywhere in code(you used 3 times).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"

        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_shop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 <include
    layout="@layout/content_shop_products_category"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabCall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/telephone_call" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```